# Order of dispatched actions in effect using merge

Tags: redux, action, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an effect that needs to return two actions. First, there is some logic involved before returning the first action. The second action is supposed to be dispatched after the first action, because it gets the data from the first action's state.

I have something like this:

```
            return Observable.combineLatest(dataRequests).pipe(
          map(res => {
            const rows = *some logic done here*                
            };
            return {
              type: types.SET_DATA,
              payload: rows;
            }
          })
          merge(observableOf({
            type: types.SAVE_DATA
          }))           
        )
```

The problem is that SAVE_DATA is getting dispatched before SET_DATA, therefore it's not able to get the data from the state. How can I modify this so SAVE_DATA is always dispatched after SET_DATA?

Answer (score 0):

fixed by replacing "merge" with "concat"